# How to use the Material UI Styled and System API with a Button in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Want to create a styled button using Material UI [Styled Components API](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#styled-components-api) and [Styled System](https://material-ui.com/system/basics/) using Typescript. Trying it like:

```
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { styled } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { compose, palette } from '@material-ui/system';

const StyledButton = styled(Button)(compose(palette));

export const ExampleButton = () => (
    <StyledButton color="primary">Click Me</StyledButton>
);
```

But im getting the following error in Typescript:

> Type '{ children: string; color: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<ButtonTypeMap<{}, "button">>>, "ref" | "form" | "slot" | ... 280 more ... | "TouchRippleProps">'.
> Types of property 'color' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"inherit" | "primary" | "secondary" | "default" | undefined'.

Seems like the color props are incompatible since its part of both, the button and the palette type definition, but are different. What would be the best solution to this problem, as I would like to be able to use other custom colors that are not part of the theme, using the system library functions?